# In application sometimes occurs Runtime Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

I have hosted my application on my server using IIS. It works excelent but sometimes it throws runtime error. my friend tested it yesterday and result was that:
[image]

but I have already set customerrors mode to off.. problem is that I can't enable this errors. I dont want that client saw that. Is there any way to make refresh if any error will occur?

In past I have tried to make defaultredirect url, i dont know why but it doesn's worked. So I want to make browser refresh in any error. Is there any way to do that? Or what'll best practice to improve that?

***Focus on that this error doesn't occur always.***

Comment: Have you looked in the event viewer of the server hosting the site to see if anything was logged there?

Comment: You should get to the bottom of whatever is causing the error, looking in windows application event log for the error details. You don't want to redirect to the original page if there is an error,  the user could very easily end up with an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: @Tim how can I do that?

Comment: @BenRobinson I dont think so. I have tested this app more than 100 times and never had faced this error. Maybe it occurs when client has opened this app for a long time. It's Facebook application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle errors using Application_Error event in global.asax.cs under app_code folder.
You can write a code to redirect user to whatever the page you wanted to on any error.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Response.Redirect("page.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting custom error to off to find out the reason, this should e set in Web.config as described in the error